# Detecting nested list id

Tags: javascript, jquery

When adding a new element via jquery, how do I define each element with a specific name or id in a nested list, depending on what currently exists?

Example:

Question 1 

 Answer 1 

 Answer 2

Add Answer

When I click "Add Answer" I'd like to add a new Answer, but know that it is "ans3". Further, there will be multiple top-level and nested lists, so it will need to know which question it's associated with.

EX)

```
Question 1

Answer 1
Answer 2

Question 2

Answer 1
Answer 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can include your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two javascript / jquery facts that will be useful to you when you design the solution for this.

1. event callbacks are bound to the object that triggered the event when they are executed.
2. DOM elements can have any number of data-* attributes that carry data with them.

So, when a user clicks a question to answer it, the click callback has access to the question as `this`.  Also, when you add a new element that is an answer, you can set a "data-question" attribute on it, that points to the ID of the question.  If you have a question like this:

```
<li class="question" id="question1">
    <span>How to detect nested list id?</span>
    <input type="text" />
    <button class="send-answer" data-questionid="question1">Add Answer</button>
</li>
```

then some javascript code like this

```
$('.send-answer').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var questionId = $(this).attr('data-questionid');
    var answer = $('#' + questionId).find(input).val();
    var answerElement = $('<span>').text(answer).attr('data-questionid', questionId);
    $('#' + questionId).append(answerElement);
}
```

will be close to getting you what you need.  There are a few other ways to skin this problem, for example instead of adding data-questionid to the button you could search the parents of the button to find the li with class question that contains it, and get the id from that element.

Comment: So for these purposes, it will be a form that you can add questions, and associated answers. When adding either questions/answers, in order to set the correct data id or id, how would I tell which id's have been used so far? Example, if ans2 and ans3 are present the next one should be ans4. Perhaps I'm thinking of this in the wrong way...

Comment: Plenty of options, you could keep a global variable and increment it every time you add an answer.  You could count the number of answers every time: `var nextAnswerId = "ans" + $('span.answer').length` (this code gives you a zero based index)